# CSS DIV - Clicking Facebook 'Send button' expands div and adds unwanted scrollbars

Tags: css, facebook, button, html, scrollbars

I'm a bit css-troubled.

How do I get the Facebook send button to pop out instead of expanding the div and adding a scrollbar to the window?! Any ideas .. Thanks a million

Try clicking the 'send button' (will not do anything to your Facebook account) and you will see that the window will expand and add scrollbars?!

http://bestofyoutube.com/go/cssprob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out the lines the `float: left` from `.videoarea` and `overflow: auto` from `.main`.